# code igniter routing issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set a rewrite rule

```
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>
```

to remove the constraint of including index.php in my url and also i have set the following

```
    $config['base_url'] = '';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
```

my custom route

```
$route['test/(:num)'] = 'test/view';
```

my challenge is my default page with the url `http://localhost:8080/skillmerce` works but whenever i have a url in the form `http://localhost:8080/skillmerce/test/3` i receive a 404 error except i change the route to something like

```
$route['skillmerce/test/(:num)'] = 'test/view';
```

please how can i resolve this have trried setting the base url but all to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess would be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = ''; # leave this as empty
```

and in routes

```
$route['skillmerce/test/(:num)'] = 'test/$1'; # add $1 at the end
```

[Read This out](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards)

Comment: The issue is i dont want to add skillmerce in the route. that's what i want to remove because it currently work with adding the skillmerce but i dont want it in my route what i want is just something like $route[test/(:num)] = 'test/views

Comment: @HordedoyinMatthewg add route like this `$route['skillmerce/test/(:num)'] = 'test/$1';`

Comment: Isn't there a way to do without adding skillmerce as pathe of my routing strings?

Comment: you can call this `test/$1` instead of this `skillmerce/test/(:num)`. **Example** `href="<?php echo base_url()>test/25"`

Comment: thanks @Spartan. Now let say again my default url is http://localhost:8080/skillmerce/ so am thinking since dis is my default url from wamp i dont need to add skillmerce to my route but currently it does not work except i add skillmerce with my route. Thanks

Comment: my default url is  localhost:8080/skillmerce so in my route if i dont include skillmerce/test/$1 i receive 404 error no matter the page am going to. Currently only the default url work all other pages return 404 if skillmerce is not appended to the route

Comment: <a href="test/3"> link</a>

Comment: its should be `<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>test/3 "> link</a>`

Comment: @HordedoyinMatthewg If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)